# Moving KVM virtual machine (AlmaLinux 8 guest) to Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, alma-linux

I am trying to move a KVM virtual machine to Hyper-V. The guest machine is an AlmaLinux 8.5. I have converted the RAW image to VHDX.

What other steps will I  need to do in order to be able to run AlmaLinux on Hyper-V? Will I need to recompile the initramfs? Can you provide me the instructions on how I would do that on AlmaLinux 8?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I moved a KVM virtual machine (AlmaLinux 8 guest) over to Hyper-V.

Copy the virtual image over to the Hyper-V host.

Convert the RAM image to VHDX. Download it here: https://cloudbase.it/qemu-img-windows/.

```
qemu-img.exe convert source.img -O vhdx -o subformat=dynamic dest.vhdx
```

When starting the virtual machine, you may get the error message "General access denied error". Run the following command in an elevated command prompt:

```
icacls <Path of .vhd or .avhd file> /grant "NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\ <Virtual Machine ID from step 1> ":(F)
```

For example

```
icacls "E:\VMs\VMName\Disk0.vhd" /grant "NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\5FC5C385-BD98-451F-B3F3-1E50E06EE663":(F)
```

Boot the virtual machine, select the rescue kernel (last kernel) in grub which contains all the kernel modules. Once booted, login and run the following command:

```
dracut -f --regenerate-all
```

Reboot to the default kernel.